# Does the method call also include the execution?

Tags: java, function, methods, language-agnostic, time-complexity

What does it mean by method call?
When the method/function is called is it immediately executed or is the function/method first called and then executed? Does it depend on the language, I would be wondering for Java. Should I keep in my head a method call as executing the method or calling the method and then executing it? I could not find a clear answer online, which led me to ask here. How can I confirm that the method call would immediately execute the function and not have any time in between?

Do they both mean the same thing by method call and method execution? In terms of time complexity would I consider them both as same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like semantics really. A method call usually refers to the line of code where the method is called, while method execution usually refers to the method executing the code inside of it. In terms of time complexity both will always be referring to how long the method takes to execute the code within it.

Comment: More specifically, the first item you described is named a _call site_.